# I would like to transform a list of numbers including ranges into a list of numbers only

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is a part of the code that I managed to do:

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL drop table #tempTable;
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#STRINGS') IS NOT NULL drop table #STRINGS;
> declare @list_range AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '330-380,400-410';
> SELECT *
> INTO #STRINGS 
> FROM string_split(@list_range,',');
> SELECT  
> PARSENAME( REPLACE([value],'-','.'),2) AS RangeStart,
> PARSENAME( REPLACE([value],'-','.'),1) AS RangeEnd
> INTO #tempTable
> FROM #STRINGS;
> WITH MSN_Numbers AS (
> SELECT 
>         CAST(RangeStart AS int) AS RangeStart, 
>         CAST(RangeStart AS int) AS num,
>         CAST(RangeEnd AS int) AS RangeEnd
>     from #tempTable
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 
>         CAST(RangeStart AS int) AS RangeStart,
>         CAST(num AS int) + 1 AS num,
>         CAST(RangeEnd AS int) AS RangeEnd
>     FROM MSN_Numbers 
>     WHERE num < RangeEnd)
> ```

how can i integrate do so that the transformation can be done with in the list of additional isolated numbers. Example:

> ```
> declare @list_range AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '320,322,330-380,388,400-410,415';
> ```

Comment: What is the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

your existing query when `PARSENAME( .. , 2)` returns `NULL` for those single value. Use `COALESCE()` to return `value` for such case.

```
SELECT  
        COALESCE(PARSENAME( REPLACE([value], '-', '.'), 2), [value]) AS RangeStart,
        PARSENAME( REPLACE([value], '-', '.'), 1) AS RangeEnd
INTO    #tempTable
FROM    #STRINGS;
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed !